# Ruby on Rails: Query rails model for a specific precision on a floating point attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, floating-point, precision

In my Rails application, I have a table of **Places** that is structured like this.

```
id <int>
name <string>
longitude float
latitude float
```

Problem is, we did not enforce any precision/scale standards on our latitude/longitude attributes. Hence, some Places may have each/both of their longitude & latitude to be greater/lesser than 6 decimal places.

I want to find all my Places that have been saved with a specific precision of latitude/longitude. Something like this:

- Get all places with longitude of 5 decimal places
- Get all places with latitude of 7 decimal places
- Get all places with longitude of 4 decimal places & latitude of 8 decimal places
- Etc

Can anyone suggest how to perform such a query using Rails active records?

P.S. I am using PostgreSQL v9.4.14

Comment: Not sure with ActiveRecord, but ruby can surely help you by going through each record.

Comment: What DB do you use?

Comment: why do you want to query the places by precision?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk using PostgreSQL

Comment: @AnaMaríaMartínezGómez it is my first step towards cleaning up my Places records by first understanding how many bad data i have.

Comment: If they are grater than 6 you could just round them and count them while doing so, or is it important to know it in advance? If they are lesser than 6, that doesn't really mean that there are bad data becase 3.600000 would be stored as 3.6 and it is impossible to know the precision afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Try as following to Get all places with longitude of 5 decimal places

```
Place.all.collect{|p| p if p.longitude.to_s.include?('.') && p.longitude.to_s.split('.').last.length == 5}
```

and also same logic for remaining.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using **Postgre**, `scale` will return the number of decimal digits in the fractional part. You may define scopes like:

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  scope :with_longitude_scale, -> (scale_limit) { where('scale(longitude) = ?', scale_limit) }
  scope :with_latitude_scale, -> (scale_limit) { where('scale(latitude) = ?', scale_limit) }
end
```

Now you can easily query the model (also chain them as needed) to return all relevant records.

- Get all places with longitude of 5 decimal places: `Place.with_longitude_scale(5)`
- Get all places with longitude of 4 decimal places **&** latitude of 8 decimal places: `Place.with_longitude_scale(4).with_latitude_scale(8)`

Comment: Sounds nice. But i am getting this error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function scale(double precision) does not exist` `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` Can suggest an alternative? Kinda new to PG.

Comment: I tried `Place.where("scale(cast(longitude as numeric)) = 6").count`

Comment: looks like `scale` is supported by PostgreSQL v9.6 onwards. I am using PG 9.4 :(